# Using vector values outside of a function

Tags: c++, scope, blackjack

**Background**

We're creating a blackjack game, and we want to deal cards to a player. We've made a function that creates a vector of numbers, and we've also been able to "shuffle" those numbers. What we want to do now is take that vector shuffled_cardvals and distribute the values to the dealer and the player.

Our problem is that we can't get shuffled_cardvals to work outside of the function. From perusing other posts, we're fairly certain our issue is that because shuffled_cardvals is used inside the function shuffle(), it doesn't exist outside of that function.

As such, we know the problem, but we can't figure out how to fix it.

**Code**

Here's our code. We're using a source file and a header file, as we thought that would make things a bit cleaner.

*main.cpp*

```
 #include <iostream>
 #include <cmath>
 #include <string>
 #include <vector>
 #include <algorithm>
 #include <sstream>
 #include "blackjack_header_functions.hpp"
 #include "BlackjackClass.hpp"

int main() {

//extern int choice;
// Intro
std::cout << "Good Evening. This is Samuel L. Jackson. Welcome to BlackJack(son). \n";

// output initial face value of cards
std::cout << "Initial face values for each player: ";

int facevalue = 0;
std::cout << "\n";

//shuffle the cards and output the results
shuffle();


// take the player to "the hub"
selectionMenu();

//std::cout << "your choice is " << choice << " biatch\n";

 return 0;
}
```

*blackjack_header_functions.hpp*

```
#include <iostream>
#include <algorithm>
#include <vector>
#include <string>
#include <ctime>
#include <cstdlib>

void selectionMenu();
void DetermineWinner();
void shuffle();

std::vector <std::string> cards = { "AC" , "AH" , "AS" , "AD" ,"KC" , "KH" , "KS" , "KD" , 
"QC" , "QH" , "QS" , "QD", "JC" , "JH" , "JS" , "JD" , "10C" , "10H" , "10S" , "10D" ,
"9C" , "9H" , "9S" , "9D" ,"8C" , "8H" , "8S" , "8D" , "7C" , "7H" , "7S" , "7D" , 
"6C" , "6H" , "6S" , "6D" , "5C" , "5H" , "5S" , "5D" , "4C" , "4H" , "4S" , "4D" , 
"3C" ,"3H" , "3S" , "3D" , "2C" , "2H" , "2S" , "2D" };


std::vector <int> cardvals = {
 2, 2, 2, 2,
 3, 3, 3, 3, 
 4, 4, 4, 4,
 5, 5, 5, 5,  
 6, 6, 6, 6,
 7, 7, 7, 7, 
 8, 8, 8, 8,
 9, 9, 9, 9, 
 10, 10, 10, 10,
 10, 10, 10, 10,
 10, 10, 10, 10,
 10, 10, 10, 10,};



std::vector <int> shuffled_cardvals = {};


std::vector <int> &x;

void shuffle(){

// First, generate a random seed for the card shuffling process.
// If we don't do this step, every time we call random_shuffle(),
// we'll get the same order of cards for our shuffled deck, making
// it not very random.

std::srand(std::time(0));

// Next, shuffle the cards and their face values
std::random_shuffle(cards.begin(), cards.end());
std::random_shuffle(cardvals.begin(), cardvals.end());

// then, put the shuffled cards in a new vector called shuffled_deck
for(int i =  0; i < cards.size(); i++) {shuffled_deck.push_back(cards[i]);}

// do it for the face values too
std::vector <int> shuffled_cardvals = {};
for(int i =  0; i < cardvals.size(); i++) {shuffled_cardvals.push_back(cardvals[i]);}

// finally, output the shuffled deck to the console
std::cout << "Shuffled deck: \n";
for(int i =  0; i < shuffled_deck.size(); i++)  {std::cout << shuffled_deck[i] << " ";}

std::cout << "\n" << "Shuffled card values: \n";
for(int i =  0; i < shuffled_cardvals.size(); i++)  {std::cout << shuffled_cardvals[i] << " ";}

 }

   void Deal(std::vector <int> &x) {

    int dealerhand = 0;
    int playerhand = 0;

    for(int i = 0; i < 4; i++) {

    dealerhand = dealerhand + x[i];
    playerhand = playerhand + x[i+1];

    }

    std::cout << "\n" << dealerhand << "\n" << playerhand;

    }
```

*Console Output (Edited/Fixed 1/4/21)*

```
      In file included from main.cpp:100:
 blackjack_header_functions.hpp:38:20: error: 'x' declared as reference but 
 not initialized
    38 | std::vector <int> &x;
       |                    ^
 blackjack_header_functions.hpp: In function 'void shuffle()':
 blackjack_header_functions.hpp:54:45: error: 'shuffled_deck' was not 
 declared in this scope
    54 |     for(int i =  0; i < cards.size(); i++) 
              {shuffled_deck.push_back(cards[i]);}
       |        ^~~~~~~~~~~~~
 blackjack_header_functions.hpp:62:25: error: 'shuffled_deck' was not 
 declared in this scope
    62 |     for(int i =  0; i < shuffled_deck.size(); i++)  {std::cout << 
         shuffled_deck[i] << " ";} ^~~~~~~~~~~~~
       |
```

**Disclaimer**

My friend and I are trying to start learning C++ together over winter break, and we're complete noobs. The code right now is in a very unfinished state, and we're sure it already has plenty of issues. Any help is appreciated!

Comment: `&shuffled_cardvals = {}` isn't in the code you've posted, please post a [mre]

Comment: You have declared shuffled_cardvals as both a local in shuffle() and a global. You probably need to pass them into shuffle as a reference like x in Deal. Also you have a global reference x in the hpp file which is not assigned and the compiler will give an error for this.

Comment: Just as a general suggestion as you are using C++: Why don't you make a class `Card` that holds all relevant card information and methods and a `Deck`class that holds several cards and has methods such as `shuffle()` etc.

Comment: @AlanBirtles I accidentally included an old error message from before I cleaned up the code and got rid of stuff. Just fixed it!

Comment: @Ian4264 so essentially, I should create shuffled_cardvals as a global variable only, and then pass it into shuffle()?

Comment: You have to declare `shuffled_deck`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Okay a few things which I am kinda worried about.

1. `std::vector <int> cardvals` and `std::vector <std::string> cards` is initialised in the header which you probably dont want. I would recommend declaring it as `extern` and initialising it in your `.cpp`. The reason for this is that each translation unit would get their own instance of that array which will cause headache :)
2. It is possible to declare the two arrays globally but usually not recommended. I would create functions which will create such arrays but it is fine the way it is.
3. What are you trying to achieve with `std::vector <int> &x;`. I am sure `std::vector <int> x;` will solve your problems :)

Since you are going for C++ instead of C, you should also write the things a bit more object orientated instead of declaring things globally which a few people consider a bad habit.

Comment: Through your guidance, we finally got it to work, and we eventually got a basic version of the game running, albeit without classes. We will now practice classes and try to implement the game with those. Thank you!